# Upgrading from 10.04 to 11.04

Tags: 11.04, upgrade, windows

I want to upgrade Ubuntu 10.04 to 11.04 offline. I have burnt a Ubuntu 11.04 CD. During the installation there's an option; "Upgrade to 11.04". Will choosing this option affect my Windows partition? I don't want my Windows partition to be affected.

Answer (score 6):

[image]

The option "upgrade 10.04 to 11.04" is not like upgrading 10.04 to 11.04 via an upgrade to 10.10.. This option means that all data from your `/home` will be preserved but you will have to reinstall your idividual applications and you will also have to create your users again. User setting from these applications (including passwords in the keyring) will be preserved.

*"Upgrade from 10.04 to 11.04"* therefore is like a clean installation (i.e. *"Erase Ubuntu and reinstall"*) but without formatting your drive and without erasing `/home`.

**As with all OS upgrades it is strongly recommended to backup your data before you proceed.**

Your Windows partition(s) will only be touched and deleted by choosing *"Erase everything"*.

Answer (score 2):

Since long ago, all LiveCD installations from Ubuntu give the option to delete the whole partition, install side by side with the OS you already have installed and even resize the partition if you want to give more or less to Ubuntu. So the answer is NO it will not delete your windows. You have to literally tell it to do so with an option that says something like "Delete the partition and install Ubuntu".

I can vouch for 9.10, 10.04, 10.10 and 11.04. Do not remember from way back more. You do not loose data, corrupt the hard drive, etc..

Answer (score 0):

The upgrade option won't touch windows, and all going to plan, should not damage your data on your Ubuntu partition either. However many things can go wrong with an update, especially with regards to the install media, so like previous posters have said, back up your data.

It certainly wouldn't hurt to put your /home data on a separate partition, at least then you can format the **system** partition, if need be, without harming either your personal files or program configurations. The programs would need to be reinstalled however

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry, Windows won't be touched if you click 'Upgrade Ubuntu 10.04 LTS to 11.04' If you click 'Erase everything and reinstall' then Windows will still be installed, but everything will be gone like Documents, Pictures, Programs etc. Just make sure that you click Upgrade Ubuntu!

Answer (score -1):

you can't upgrade from 10.04 to 11.04, you need to upgrade to 10.10 first od do a clean install of 11.04. Do as you wish and luck ;)

Comment: This answer is not valid. As @Takkat said, you **can** upgrade from 10.04 to 11.04.