# How to upgrade from 10.04 to 11.10

Tags: 10.04, upgrade, 11.10

I just tried 11.10 on virtualbox and it seems to be fine. Rather than making another partition, transfering files, and then deleting 10.04 to make sure everything's all right, I would like to just upgrade to 11.10. Is it possible?

Comment: I guess that a simple `update-manager -d` will do the job.

Comment: It's basically the same as in the previous release: http://askubuntu.com/questions/52332/upgrading-from-10-04-to-11-04/52368#52368

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to skip releases during an upgrade?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/45666/is-it-possible-to-skip-releases-during-an-upgrade)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not directly; you must first upgrade to 10.10, then 11.04.  You can only skip releases when upgrading from LTS to LTS.

Comment: do you live in S-America ?

Answer (score 1):

To my memory you can upgrade from 10.04 to 11.10, but as psusi suggests, you *should* upgrade to 10.10 and then 11.04 first for best results.