# Update from 10.10 to 12.04 without backup

Tags: 12.04, 10.10

I want to update by ubuntu 10.10 to 12.04 LTS. Is there any way i can do it without backing up the data that is there in my drive. I have been using 10.10 for a long time. And i like the new 12.04 LTS and have used it for a while on my friends laptop. Thank you.

Comment: You know the old saying: there are two kinds of people, those who do backups and those who *will* do backups. Not having a backup is an awful idea.

Comment: :) i come in the one who never wants to do a backup

Comment: See also here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/52332/upgrading-from-10-04-to-11-04 (the procedures did not chnage)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been updating/re-installing Ubuntu without a backup for several releases now.

My method is to use 2 partitions and keep all the personal data on that 2nd disc away from your system. I have `/` and `/home` on 1 disc but my `/home` does not hold any personal data. So I can either format `/` and/or `/home` without loosing anything. All I do at the end of the re-install is remove all directories in home and point them to my 2nd harddisc (where the actual files are). And a F5 on the desktop gives me back my icons on the desktop.

So yes, it can be done but if you did not set this up yet then you probably are best of burning your stuff to a cd, dvd or to store it online. **A backup is always adviced**

Answer (score 1):

You can upgrade without updating it will not delete your data but maybe some of the your softwares that are not supported by 12.04 will be deleted. But, ***I advice you to backup and never think to upgrade without backup***.

Comment: "never say never" - if you choose to "Erase everything" on upgrading it will erase everything including your personal data.

Comment: upgrading will not remove your data. It will affect only application out of the box