# Accounts lost during in-line upgrade Ubuntu 10.04 -> 11.10

Tags: upgrade, users

I recently upgraded an Ubuntu box from 10.04 to 11.10.  During the upgrade process, all of the accounts except the one I created on installation were lost, and had to be recovered.  Subsequently, I upgraded the SAME box to 12.04 from 11.10, and the accounts remained. I'm wondering why this is.  Did something change from 10.x to 11.x/12.x?  I think that Ubuntu may have switched to GNOME 3...
I'm just wondering why it only happened in the first case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you observed is the expected behaviour.

We are only able to upgrade from one release to the next or from an LTS-release to the next LTS-release without losing user settings and accounts. All other "upgrades" are basically a new installation but without erasing our `/home` directory. Accounts and applications will have to be set up again then.

If you had upgraded from 10.04 LTS to 12.04 LTS as a proper upgrade path your accounts would have been preserved. With an interim upgrade via 11.10 this was not possible.

See also the following questions:

- [Upgrading from 10.04 to 11.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/52332/upgrading-from-10-04-to-11-04)
- [Can I skip over releases when upgrading?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34430/can-i-skip-over-releases)