# Ubuntu reinstall without losing /home?

Tags: installation, home-directory

I got to a state when upgrade is not possible - old system (10.10, packages index too broken)
I dediced to reinstall.

Now I'd like to keep my /home.
Ideally, I'd like to burn a CD or ISO to USB and click Next, Next, Next.

How should I proceed?

Comment: Do you have your Home on a different partition?

Comment: With 12.04 + you can just install, separate /home partition or not. Either way, make a back up before installing, you need to back up important data anyways.

Comment: The "upgrade" will be similar to this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/52332/upgrading-from-10-04-to-11-04

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely backup your `/home` directory.

Also, I would consider backing up your `/etc/` directory and other places that may contain programs or customized files or settings (such as `.config`).

If `/home` is on a separate partition, then you can just reuse it. Take care that you doesn't toggle the `format` option to "on" in the partitioning dialog.

That aside, my advice is that you start from scratch and re-partition your disk.
IMHO, you will need a bigger `/usr/` partition than you did with 10.10.
Also, you can upgrade from the *ext3* filsystem to *ext4*, and perhaps you could even consider migrating to *LVM*.

Answer (score 1):

While it would be preferable to make a backup of your data, you should simply be able to "reinstall" Ubuntu (that should be an option on the live USB); it will keep all the programs it can and it should not touch your documents (ie /home/).
However, I've only tried this when upgrading newer releases to the newest and while it should work with 10.10, I strongly encourage you to backup your data. (If you need free storage, you could try [Mega](http://mega.co.nz/) - you get 50GB for free).